# Determine the number of paths of length 2 in a complete graph of n nodes

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics

Question: Determine the number of paths of length 2 in a completed graph of n nodes. Give your answer in Big-O notation as a function of n

So I started working on this problem however I know im doing something wrong

So a complete graph is when every pair of distinct vertices is connected by a unique edge.

[image: patterns]
So i started drawing graphs with different number of nodes and found the number of paths depending on the number of nodes and across this equation for n number of nodes Kn = n(n-2)/2. Now the path length has to be two so would the equation be (n(n-2)/2)/2. Im confused someone please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: To build a path of length two, choose the initial vertex, then the middle vertex, then the final vertex.  This double-counts since you could have picked in reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given three vertices there are three paths of length two on those three vertices. The answer is hence $3\binom{n}{3}$

Comment: so what is big O notation for that? or a equation for that answer?

Comment: Big O-notation is usually used to describe how fast a function grows, but here  it makes no sense to do so because we can give the exact formula explicitly.